# Generating custom manifests with Maven and multiple specially-named classpaths

Tags: java, maven, classpath, manifest

I'm trying to implement a Maven build process for YAJSW (Yet Another Java Service Wrapper). The part I'm currently working on is generating a custom manifest for the jar to ape the format used in the currently hard-coded [MANIFEST.MF](https://github.com/griels/yajsw-maven/blob/30a10d2dd9ef13a196c9192cc8b3035d5f243f6c/yajsw-maven-git/build/MANIFEST.MF) file, like so:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path-Wrapper-Core: 
./wrapperApp.jar 
./lib/core/yajsw/ahessian.jar 
.
.
.
./lib/core/regex/jrexx-1.1.1.jar

Class-Path-Wrapper-Extended: 
./lib/extended/commons/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar 
./lib/extended/commons/commons-codec-1.3.jar 
.
.
./lib/extended/abeille/formsrt.jar

Class-Path-App: 
./wrapper.jar 
.
.
./lib/core/commons/commons-logging-1.1.jar

Main-Class: org.rzo.yajsw.boot.WrapperExeBooter
```

I've managed to produce suitably formatted classpaths using the dependency:build-dep task like so:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-classpath</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-classpath</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <attach>true</attach>
                        <localRepoProperty>.</localRepoProperty>
                        <pathSeparator>$${pathDelim}</pathSeparator>

                        <outputFile>${basedir}/target/assembly/classPath</outputFile>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

**N.B. the $${pathDelim} part was arrived at after much experimentation with escaping, antrun and properties. Initially I tried to add newlines directly using the pathSeparator parameter. I found that the only way I could do this was to use $${line.separator}. Seems there's an extra layer of de-escaping that happens somewhere in the pipeline.**

This code successfully generates a classPath file in the required format. Now I had to merge this into a MANIFEST.MF file.

On reviewing all the options, I've done this using an [Antrun task](https://github.com/griels/yajsw-maven/blob/0a5bf8248d8ee7f1b656729ff199518e1f68d806/yajsw-maven-git/pom.xml) :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="cp.props"
                                value="${basedir}/target/assembly/classPath.properties" />

                            <concat destfile="${cp.props}">
                                <string>wrapper.core.classpath=</string>
                                <filelist dir="${basedir}/target/assembly" files="classPath" />
                            </concat>
                            <property file="${cp.props}" />
                            <echo file="${MANIFEST}"
                                message="Manifest-Version: 1.0${line.separator}Class-Path-Wrapper-Core: ${line.separator}
                ${wrapper.core.classpath}${line.separator}
                ${line.separator}
                Class-Path-Wrapper-Extended: ${line.separator}
                ${wrapper.core.classpath}${line.separator}
                ${line.separator}
                Class-Path-App: ${line.separator}
                ${wrapper.core.classpath}${line.separator}
                ${line.separator}
                Main-Class: org.rzo.yajsw.boot.WrapperExeBooter${line.separator}" />
                            <replace file="${MANIFEST}" token="${pathDelim}" value=" " />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This produced more or less the correct output in the MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Class-Path-Wrapper-Core: 
    ./commons-daemon/commons-daemon/1.0.10/commons-daemon-1.0.10.jar ./commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.7-SNAPSHOT/commons-configuration-1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar ...

    Class-Path-Wrapper-Extended: 
    ./commons-daemon/commons-daemon/1.0.10/commons-daemon-1.0.10.jar ./commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.7-SNAPSHOT/commons-configuration-1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar ...

    Class-Path-App: 
    ./commons-daemon/commons-daemon/1.0.10/commons-daemon-1.0.10.jar ./commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.7-SNAPSHOT/commons-configuration-1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar ...

    Main-Class: org.rzo.yajsw.boot.WrapperExeBooter
```

which I then pointed to in the jar plugin settings:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <useDefaultManifestFile>false</useDefaultManifestFile>
                <archive> <manifestFile>${MANIFEST}</manifestFile> </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

However, looking in the resultant jar, it seems to have flattened the output, like so:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0     Class-Path-Wrapper-Core: ./commons-daemon/commons-daemon/1.0.10/commons-daemon-1.0.10.jar ./commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.7-SNAPSHOT/commons-configuration-1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar ./commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar ./commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar ./commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar ./commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8.1/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar ./commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.3/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar ./org/apache/commons/commons-cli/2.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-cli-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ./commons-io/commons-io/1.3.1/commons-io-1.3.1.jar ./org/apache/commons/commons-vfs/2.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-vfs-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ./commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.0/commons-httpclient-3.0.jar ./commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar ./org/apache/commons/commons-vfs2/2.0/commons-vfs2-2.0.jar ./org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-api/1.4/maven-scm-api-1.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-svnexe/1.4/maven-scm-provider-svnexe-1.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons/1.4/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons-1.4.jar ./regexp/regexp/1.3/regexp-1.3.jar ./org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.8.6/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar ./net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar ./net/java/dev/jna/platform/3.4.0/platform-3.4.0.jar ./io/netty/netty/3.3.1.Final/netty-3.3.1.Final.jar ./jrexx/jrexx/1.1.1/jrexx-1.1.1.jar ./org/rzo/ahessian/yajsw.11.0/ahessian-yajsw.11.0.jar ./org/quartz-scheduler/quartz/1.8.0/quartz-1.8.0.jar ./javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar ./org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.10/slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar ./org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.5.10/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar ./log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14.jar ./org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.6.3/velocity-1.6.3.jar ./oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar ./com/caucho/hessian/4.0.7/hessian-4.0.7.jar ./com/jgoodies/forms/1.2.0/forms-1.2.0.jar ./net/java/dev/glazedlists/glazedlists_java15/1.8.0/glazedlists_java15-1.8.0.jar ./com/jeta/abeille/forms/1.0/forms-1.0.jar ./org/codehaus/mojo/properties-maven-plugin/1.0-alpha-1/properties-maven-plugin-1.0-alpha-1.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.0.4/maven-model-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0/maven-plugin-api-2.0.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.4/maven-project-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.0.4/maven-settings-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.0.4/maven-profile-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.4/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0.4/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/1.0-alpha-6/wagon-provider-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.4/maven-artifact-2.0.4.jar ./org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9.jar ./junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar ./classworlds/classworlds/1.1-alpha-2/classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar ./org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar          Class-Path-Wrapper-Extended: ./commons-daemon/commons-daemon/1.0.10/commons-daemon-1.0.10.jar ./commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.7-SNAPSHOT/commons-configuration-1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar ./commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar ./commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar ./commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar ./commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8.1/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar ./commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.3/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar ./org/apache/commons/commons-cli/2.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-cli-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ./commons-io/commons-io/1.3.1/commons-io-1.3.1.jar ./org/apache/commons/commons-vfs/2.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-vfs-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ./commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.0/commons-httpclient-3.0.jar ./commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar ./org/apache/commons/commons-vfs2/2.0/commons-vfs2-2.0.jar ./org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-api/1.4/maven-scm-api-1.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-svnexe/1.4/maven-scm-provider-svnexe-1.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons/1.4/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons-1.4.jar ./regexp/regexp/1.3/regexp-1.3.jar ./org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.8.6/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar ./net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar ./net/java/dev/jna/platform/3.4.0/platform-3.4.0.jar ./io/netty/netty/3.3.1.Final/netty-3.3.1.Final.jar ./jrexx/jrexx/1.1.1/jrexx-1.1.1.jar ./org/rzo/ahessian/yajsw.11.0/ahessian-yajsw.11.0.jar ./org/quartz-scheduler/quartz/1.8.0/quartz-1.8.0.jar ./javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar ./org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.10/slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar ./org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.5.10/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar ./log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14.jar ./org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.6.3/velocity-1.6.3.jar ./oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar ./com/caucho/hessian/4.0.7/hessian-4.0.7.jar ./com/jgoodies/forms/1.2.0/forms-1.2.0.jar ./net/java/dev/glazedlists/glazedlists_java15/1.8.0/glazedlists_java15-1.8.0.jar ./com/jeta/abeille/forms/1.0/forms-1.0.jar ./org/codehaus/mojo/properties-maven-plugin/1.0-alpha-1/properties-maven-plugin-1.0-alpha-1.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.0.4/maven-model-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0/maven-plugin-api-2.0.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.4/maven-project-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.0.4/maven-settings-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.0.4/maven-profile-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.4/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0.4/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/1.0-alpha-6/wagon-provider-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.4/maven-artifact-2.0.4.jar ./org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9.jar ./junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar ./classworlds/classworlds/1.1-alpha-2/classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar ./org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar          Class-Path-App: ./commons-daemon/commons-daemon/1.0.10/commons-daemon-1.0.10.jar ./commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.7-SNAPSHOT/commons-configuration-1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar ./commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar ./commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar ./commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar ./commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8.1/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar ./commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.3/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar ./org/apache/commons/commons-cli/2.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-cli-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ./commons-io/commons-io/1.3.1/commons-io-1.3.1.jar ./org/apache/commons/commons-vfs/2.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-vfs-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ./commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.0/commons-httpclient-3.0.jar ./commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar ./org/apache/commons/commons-vfs2/2.0/commons-vfs2-2.0.jar ./org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-api/1.4/maven-scm-api-1.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-svnexe/1.4/maven-scm-provider-svnexe-1.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons/1.4/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons-1.4.jar ./regexp/regexp/1.3/regexp-1.3.jar ./org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.8.6/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar ./net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar ./net/java/dev/jna/platform/3.4.0/platform-3.4.0.jar ./io/netty/netty/3.3.1.Final/netty-3.3.1.Final.jar ./jrexx/jrexx/1.1.1/jrexx-1.1.1.jar ./org/rzo/ahessian/yajsw.11.0/ahessian-yajsw.11.0.jar ./org/quartz-scheduler/quartz/1.8.0/quartz-1.8.0.jar ./javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar ./org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.10/slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar ./org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.5.10/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar ./log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14.jar ./org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.6.3/velocity-1.6.3.jar ./oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar ./com/caucho/hessian/4.0.7/hessian-4.0.7.jar ./com/jgoodies/forms/1.2.0/forms-1.2.0.jar ./net/java/dev/glazedlists/glazedlists_java15/1.8.0/glazedlists_java15-1.8.0.jar ./com/jeta/abeille/forms/1.0/forms-1.0.jar ./org/codehaus/mojo/properties-maven-plugin/1.0-alpha-1/properties-maven-plugin-1.0-alpha-1.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.0.4/maven-model-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0/maven-plugin-api-2.0.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.4/maven-project-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.0.4/maven-settings-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.0.4/maven-profile-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.4/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0.4/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.4.jar ./org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/1.0-alpha-6/wagon-provider-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar ./org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.4/maven-artifact-2.0.4.jar ./org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9.jar ./junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar ./classworlds/classworlds/1.1-alpha-2/classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar ./org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar          Main-Class: org.rzo.yajsw.boot.WrapperExeBooter
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: 20.0-b11 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

---

P.S.On further inspection, it appears this flattening is mostly a natural consequence of the jar-building process, and happened in the original Gradle build too. However, I still have all the classpaths on one line, and need to keep them separate... I wonder if this is as a result of the merging of multiple discrete manifests by Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the indentation in the POM file was causing spaces to appear in the generated MANIFEST.MF file, and those spaces were being interpreted as indication of line continuation.

I've rejigged the antrun section [as follows](https://github.com/griels/yajsw-maven/tree/58235e560c0d11f10a865c78f593c435190f0db7/yajsw-maven-git/pom.xml):

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="cp.props"
                                value="${basedir}/target/assembly/classPath.properties" />
                            <property name="ls" value="${line.separator}"/>

                            <concat destfile="${cp.props}">
                                <string>wrapper.core.classpath=</string>
                                <filelist dir="${basedir}/target/assembly" files="classPath" />
                            </concat>
                            <property file="${cp.props}" />
                            <echo file="${MANIFEST}"
                                message="Manifest-Version: 1.0
                ${ls}Class-Path-Wrapper-Core: ${ls} ${wrapper.core.classpath}${ls}
                ${ls}Class-Path-Wrapper-Extended: ${ls} ${wrapper.core.classpath}${ls}
                ${ls}Class-Path-App: ${ls} ${wrapper.core.classpath}${ls}
                ${ls}Main-Class: org.rzo.yajsw.boot.WrapperExeBooter${ls}" />
                            <replace file="${MANIFEST}" token="${pathDelim}" value=" " />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

YAJSW seems a bit happier now when referencing the classpaths in the .jar, although I haven't got it quite right yet. Still, pretty happy with this outcome! Hope all my findings are of use to someone - I couldn't find this info on SO or in the Maven docs.